# Time Machine only shows 'case-sensitive' after formatting backup drive, fails and asks it to be renamed, leading to other problems

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I always thought any *nix-based system like OS X would be *case-sensitive*, although (just tested to make sure!) on Big Sur I cannot create 'FILE1' and 'file1' in the same folder, so it appears *case-insensitive*.

However, after it has formatted my backup drive, **Time Machine** only has a "case sensitive" option? The drive is shown at the top (as the external drive icon and title, not selectable, with only "Remove Disk" as an option) with the same Time Machine icon and same drive name beneath it, marked 'Case-sensitive'—I presume this is the usual interface and default choice?

After the first attempt, however, Time Machine fails (red question mark to right) and asks me to rename "one of the disks" (when there's only one connected) to a long string: "APPLE SSD APO512M Media - Data" although renaming it simply causes Time Machine to show two identically-named disks

[image: Time Machine long backup name]

However, after renaming to the string above and relaunching Time Machine, my renamed disk appeared twice (again) and on choosing the second case-sensitive (and only possible) option in the list of external disks the backup went ahead. Why the two identically-named disks, with one marked "case-sensitive"? After the first renaming from "backup| to the above, Time Machine showed the following:

[image: Confusing external drive names]

But "Backup" changed to the long name as soon as I selected "choose" for the second disk (with the long name) in the list.

I do a lot of web development on Linux servers, so I'm used to case-sensitivity, and I don't use any Adobe products (I understand they clash with case-sensitive drives) so what issues might I encounter with my separate but very similar backups from two non-M1 laptops running Big Sur or later?

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Me...⁩ 563.2 MB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 313.4 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                622.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Me...⁩ 114.7 GB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Media⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s7
   7:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s7s1

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk2
   1:         Microsoft Reserved ⁨⁩                        134.2 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         5.0 TB     disk2s2
```

Without the external drive:

```
% diskutil list internal
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Me...⁩ 562.8 MB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 313.4 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                622.8 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Me...⁩ 126.9 GB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Media⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s7
   7:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s7s1
```

Running `diskutil ap listgroups` after removing the extra (case insensitive) disc via the Time Machine interface:

```
diskutil ap listgroups
APFS Containers (2 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 817F6958-3C62-4EDB-A445-A960AF3396E8
|   |
|   +-> Volume Group B696A136-89E9-4997-9E61-0061EC256CB0
|       =================================================
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s5 (Data)
|       Name:                      APPLE SSD APO512M Media - Data
|       Volume UUID:               B696A136-89E9-4997-9E61-0061EC256CB0
|       Capacity Consumed:         119796424704 B (119.8 GB)
|       -------------------------------------------------
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s7 (System)
|       Name:                      APPLE SSD APO512M Media
|       Volume UUID:               684AFD14-2E4E-4CDC-AD01-F8FC648F692A
|       Capacity Consumed:         15332147200 B (15.3 GB)
|
+-- Container disk3 D68F4756-2B56-47E9-8E3A-AF8F0F132ADD
    |
    +-> No Volume Groups among 1 Volume
daveeveritt@Daves-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

Finally, what I see (I added comments about what each contains on Jean_JD's answer). I have no idea yet what my Time Machine backups contain:

[image]

Comment: If I recall correctly you will find that the file systems on macOS are case *preserving* but not-case sensitive in the way that Linux/Unix is. As macOS is (for all intents and purposes) a consumer focused OS, I guess that Apple decided that most people don't understand that "aFILe" is not the same as "afile." I think there is an option to format a disk as "case sensitive" but you will likely find that breaks a lot of apps.

Comment: Can you add to your question the results in text mode of the terminal command `diskutil list`?

Comment: Default format is case-insensitive [though as Steve mentioned, case-preserving] but case sensitive can be chosen at format. The two don't mix well & case-insensitive is preferred unless you *must* have sensitive. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX4Ef.png

Comment: There was no option for "Case insensitive"? @Jean_JD added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is a that you have two volumes named "APPLE SSD APO512M Media - Data"
It's the message given by Time Machine.

I think this one is to delete :

```
 1:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Me...⁩ 563.2 MB   disk1s1
```

You can verify by this command :

```
diskutil ap listgroups
```

The system group would be constitued by this two volumes :

```
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Me...⁩ 114.7 GB   disk1s5
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD APO512M Media⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s7
```

Data for disk1s5

System for disk1s7

If ok you can delete the excess volume :

```
diskutil ap deletevolume disk1s1
```

And after your Time Machine save should no longer be a problem

Comment: I saw that, but I only have a single external drive plugged in? As soon as I started Time Machine, the "Backup" (which I'd named the external previously) and only two "APPLE SSD APO512M Media⁩" appeared, renamed as advised by Time Machine. Yet only one external drive is plugged in?

Comment: Also, while Time Machine was "preparing" after the first attempt (which I think worked but no idea how to check) after the machine had slept, applications wouldn't launch, my machine froze and eventually I had to quit the Finder and force-shutdown, as it wasn't responding. After a restart I had to stop Time Machine and unplug the drive to get up and running again…

Comment: Can you give the actual result of `diskutil list internal `?

Comment: added to my post above, without the external drive plugged in

Comment: Ok. My response above give you the solution : **suppress the unnecessary volume disk1s1**  then your TM save must work?

Comment: I'm too cautious to delete that without knowing more about the command (what exactly it is that I'm deleting) so I removed the duplicate disc in the Time Machine interface, which leaves me with the case-sensitive external backup drive Time Machine formatted after asking me to name it APPLE SSD APO512M Media - Data". I've just set it going: "Preparing backup". The TM interface told me my last backup was the date that led me to post this question in the first place…

Comment: Can you give te results of terminal command : `diskutil ap listgroups`to verify thr function of the presents volumes?

Comment: seems to have worked this time, after that deletion via the TM interface, which I presume is the same as `diskutil ap deletevolume disk1s1` although "disc1s1" is still showing up with `diskutil list internal`. I have no idea. But thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Happy for you. Just to verify, can you add to your initial question the actual result of `diskutil list internal` ?

Comment: I just ran it again, but it's identical (apart from slight changes in the 'size' column) to the second `diskutil list internal` readout I added to my question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you see two "Data" partitions on Macintosh HD ?.
If yes, this is causing the problem.
Cheers.

[image]

(Dave): posting screenshot here, see comment:

[image]

Comment: I do, but on opening them (right click, show in finder) despite the names in Disc Utility, one "APPLE SSD APO512M Media" contains the system and Applications installed globally, while "APPLE SSD APO512M Media - Data" contains my locally installed applications (via Homebrew).

The External drive is also named "APPLE SSD APO512M Media - Data" because Time Machine requested it be renamed thus. It's hard for me to make sense of it, but the backup at least runs, although I have no idea what it's backing up, and I cannot open the Time Machine folders inside.

Answer (score 1):

I have run in to the same issue. I have chosen the patrition (counting 831 KB) and actualy it was confusing the Time Machine. I removed it by clicking the minus sign and everything is back to normal again.

[image]

Comment: interesting - things are definitely buggy. If I turn on auto backup, it goes into eternal 'preparing' and then all sorts of issues happen, forcing me to force-shutdown to get anything working again. Considering doing an online session with Apple help.